# iPad Device Orientation Problems when Testing on Simulator

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios-simulator, orientation

In an app that I'm creating, I have set the deployment device orientation to landscape only and in my view controller I have entered the below code:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}
```

When I use the simulator (for iPad, iPhone works fine), the iPad orientation loads as portrait and then changes to landscape. Because of this, all my images are distorted due to the change from portrait to landscape. Also, when trying the find the frame height and frame width, the values returned are back to front due to the orientation loading in portrait first. When testing on a device however, these problems don't occur.

I use the simulator a lot more then a device (due to not owning every device type), so does anybody know how I'm able to get the simulator to work correctly or can anybody see what I've doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `info.plist` `Supported interface orientation (iPad)` delete `Item0` and `Item1` those with `Portrait` orientation.

[image]

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: Awesome, this has sorted out the problems. Thanks!